# Using Boost Bind with std::Transform

Tags: c++, boost, stl, bind

I'm not sure what the following code snippet with `boost::bind` is doing here:

```
//..
Instrument::Exchanges e; 
// typedef for std::vector<Instrument::Exchange>

std::transform(exchangeMap_.begin(), exchangeMap_.end(),
std::back_inserter(e), 
boost::bind(&ExchangeMap::value_type::second, _1));
//..
```

`ExchangeMap` is a typedef for `std::map<int, Instrument::Exchange>`.

I read the following [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu) but came up short. I'm assuming `&ExchangeMap::value_type::second` expands to `ExchangeMap::pair<const int, Instrument::Exchange>::second` hence a pointer to an `Instrument::Exchange`?

Answer (score 0):

`&ExchangeMap::value_type::second` is a [pointer to a (data) member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) of `ExchangeMap::value_type` (Which is `std::pair<const int, Instrument::Exchange>`).

`boost::bind` (and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) take any [invokable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) value, including pointer to members. For pointer to data members, invoke takes a value for `*this`, and returns the value for that member (So all the `pair_object.second` values).

For example:

```cpp
using pair_type = std::pair<const int, char>;

pair_type pair{ 0, 'a' };
char pair_type::* ptr = &pair_type::second;

std::invoke(ptr, pair) == 'a';
&std::invoke(ptr, pair) == &pair.second;
```

So `std::bind` just makes it a callable (in the traditional `operator()` sense) to be passed to `std::transform`, and inserts all the values of the map into `e` (ordered by the key)

Comment: So let me just confirm, we have a pointer to the data members which in this case is the value of all keys in the map. But why the `_1` placeholder? Is this somehow related to the `*this` you discussed above?